# problems getting canon mg2920 to work with latest 64bit desktop version of Ubuntu. Did my legwork!

Tags: canon, pixma

I cant seem to get my printer to work.
I followed the directions here: https://sites.google.com/site/tipsandtricksforubuntu/printer-info/canon-drivers

My printer isnt listed, so im forced to choose another (similar) model, or if I use the (recommended) generic text only driver, it doesnt print the entire page. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to go to canon to see if they had a driver for linux, but their site is currently not working. Did you check to see if they had a linux driver, preferably a .deb package?

Comment: They dont. When I choose Linux, it said that the drivers are included with the OS

Comment: did you add the canon driver ppa?

Comment: I couldnt figure out how to do that. Maybe thats the hang up?

Comment: sorry, yes I did do that.

Comment: After adding the PPA did you update your system?
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Yes, I did that too. I tried it on 2 different machines with this printer. Is it possible that its just not supported?

Answer (score 0):

According to Canon:

> "There is no driver for the OS Version you selected. The driver may be included in your OS or you may not need a driver."

In other words if Ubuntu doesn't support it, then you have to [build your own driver](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/openprinting/writingandpackagingprinterdrivers).

It's not a bad idea to try to use a driver for a different model, but this usually yields poor results.

Comment: Thanks for this! I am going to look for a printer that is compatible for ubuntu.